# How to make a div max width if the screen is under 750 px (bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX9Zh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdEVT.png)
I have made 2 divs (see screenshots). If the screen size goed under 750px, I want to make both divs max width so it would look nices. Here is the code of the divs.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="width: 45%; height: 225px;" class="kt-portlet float-left">
                <div class="kt-portlet__head">
                    <div class="kt-portlet__head-label">
                        <h3 class="kt-portlet__head-title">Wallet</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="kt-portlet__body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-borderless" style="font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <tr>
                                <th width="50%">Balance</th>
                                <td>&euro; {{ customer.balance | price }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<div class="kt-portlet w-75 float-right">
            <div class="kt-portlet__head">
                <div class="kt-portlet__head-label">
                    <h3 class="kt-portlet__head-title">Wallet Transactions</h3>
                    <div class="row ml-3">
                        <a href="{{ path('admin_ticket_create', {'customer': customer.id}) }}" class="btn btn-label btn-label-brand"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Add Credit</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row ml-3">
                        <a href="{{ path('admin_ticket_create', {'customer': customer.id}) }}" class="btn btn-label-danger btn-label-brand"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>Remove Credit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="kt-portlet__head-toolbar">
                    <div class="kt-portlet__head-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search"
                                   aria-controls="ticketsTable" id="search">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX9Zh.png)

Comment: Where's the problem? write your own rule with mediaquery....

Comment: Just a tip, don't use float to align element's use flexbox or grid layout

Comment: give width division as sum is total of 100% and don't give float
so that it will take same layout almost on every screen
like 100% fluid-container
and the 30% and 70% below ratio

Comment: use .col-md-6  on .kt-portlet, it will take 100% width below 767px and 50% above it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your html a little bit and take advantage of bootstrap,
remove floats, use col classes

```html
<div class="row">
  <div style=" height: 225px;" class="col-md-6 kt-portlet ">
    <div class="kt-portlet__head">
      <div class="kt-portlet__head-label">
        <h3 class="kt-portlet__head-title">Wallet</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kt-portlet__body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-borderless" style="font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 0;">
          <tr>
            <th width="50%">Balance</th>
            <td>&euro; {{ customer.balance | price }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="kt-portlet col-md-6">
    <div class="kt-portlet__head">
      <div class="kt-portlet__head-label">
        <h3 class="kt-portlet__head-title">Wallet Transactions</h3>
        <div class="row ml-3">
          <a href="{{ path('admin_ticket_create', {'customer': customer.id}) }}" class="btn btn-label btn-label-brand"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Add Credit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="row ml-3">
          <a href="{{ path('admin_ticket_create', {'customer': customer.id}) }}" class="btn btn-label-danger btn-label-brand"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>Remove Credit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="kt-portlet__head-toolbar">
        <div class="kt-portlet__head-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="ticketsTable" id="search" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```